# how to generate unique max id from Data Base

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a Applicant Registration form where Applicant Registration ID is generated by "Select Max(ID)...." Query. when this query is fetch out the MaxID from Data Base then i increment this ID by Plus one(+1) in this way i generate a Registration ID for all Applicant who register himself. But there is one problem occurred when i run my project from server and multiple clients (Approximately 10) Applicant try to Register then there is "primary key violation exception" occurred. There is 5 Insert Query is executed one-by-one after Max Query is executed

Code is Given Below

```
public long getUid()
    {
        try
        {
            string qry = "select isnull(max(Temp_Applicant_RegNo),0) as appregno FROM Temp_Reg";
            if (cs.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cs.Open();
            }
            cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, cs);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            long cid = 0;
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                cid = long.Parse(dr["appregno"].ToString());
                cid++;
            }
            if (cs.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cs.Close();
            }
            return cid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_ErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message; 
            return 0;
        }
    }



protected void Save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlTransaction trn = null;
        try
        {
             long Regid = getUid();      
             con.Open();
             trn = con.BeginTransaction();

             cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into....", con, trn);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", Regid);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

             cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into....", con, trn);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", Regid);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

             cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into....", con, trn);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", Regid);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

             trn.Commit();
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_ErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message;
            trn.Rollback();
        }
 }
```

Please give me suggestion that how can i generate Max ID for Applicant so that there is no chance to any duplication. Because i am working in live project.

for there i am using Asp.net C#

Comment: Don't select MAX(ID) and then increment it.  Use an `IDENTITY` in your primary key so that the database generates the key for you.

Comment: Another option is to use SEQUENCE if you are on SQL Server 2012/2014.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, let the database generate the key for you when you insert a new row. Here is for example how to do it with [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) or [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html). If you really want to do it on the client, use GUIDs as keys because you can generate them without consulting the database. There are some minor issues with GUIDs as keys because they are usually partially random and this may have negative performance effects on clustered indices, but for 99.9 % of all databases they are just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution 1:

You can create a table with only one column, For example "GeneralID", and in your application  control this Id to insert in another tables.

1. Solution 2:

Another solution is create a table and only one column, and a trigger to each table before insert to popule the id getting frmo the "Ids table" to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Before we had auto incrementing columns we would have a table to hold the IDs. It would only have 2 columns IdType varchar(10) and NextId int.  Then in a stored proc we would have something like:

```
while(1=1)
begin
    select @nextId = nextId
    from MyIds
    where IdType=@IdType

    update MyIds
    set nextId = @nextId + 1
    where IdType=@IdType
    and nextId = @nextId

    if(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        break;
end 

select @nextId as nextId
```

Note that this would only update in the second statement if the nextId didn't change. If it did change it would try again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see when do you save the new value into Temp_Reg, but how if you save that value immediately after calculation, then you can safety update others tables:

```
public long getUid()
{
    try
    {
        string qry = "select isnull(max(Temp_Applicant_RegNo),0) as appregno FROM Temp_Reg";
        if (cs.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cs.Open();
        }
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, cs);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        long cid = 0;
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            cid = long.Parse(dr["appregno"].ToString());
            cid++;
        }

UPDATE Temp_reg HERE !!!!

        if (cs.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cs.Close();
        }
        return cid;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_ErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message; 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you'll have to take this update into account inside the catch block of Save_btn_Click.

All of this if you can't use Autonumbers but If you can, use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you could change your field `Temp_Applicant_RegNo` in an IDENTITY column, then you don't need to worry about the next number assigned to your table `Temp_Reg`. It is all a jopb made by your database.
All you need to know is what number has been assigned and use that number in your subsequent inserts.
This could be easily done using the [SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) after the insert in your

```
protected void Save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlTransaction trn = null;
    try
    {
         con.Open();
         trn = con.BeginTransaction();

         cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into....; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con, trn);
         int Regid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

         cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into....", con, trn);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", Regid);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into....", con, trn);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", Regid);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         trn.Commit();
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lbl_ErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message;
        trn.Rollback();
    }
```

The trick is possible adding the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as a second query to the first insert and then call ExecuteScalar. ExecuteScalar executes the queries and then returns the value of the first column in the first row of the last query executed.

Comment: OK, i will try it. but what happen when multiple client interact at same time? means if there is 2 or more user they are interact at same time then SCOPE_IDENTITY() return a value of last executed query to every client.